Would it be possible to convince a hungry alien species that human lives are valuable?
Suppose that:

an extraterrestrial species comes to earth
they are vastly more intelligent than us, and are capable of easily overpowering us militarily
they have moral intuitions, but different from ours
they find it intuitively obvious that there's nothing wrong in members of one species eating members of other less-intelligent species
they don't find it intuitively obvious that human lives are instrinsically valuable
they discover an appreciation for eating humans

Two intertwined questions: (1) How could one of us begin to try to convince them that killing humans for consuption is somehow wrong? (2) If there's no way to convince them of such wrongness, could it mean that we were somehow mistaken in holding this belief?

You are an astronaut and you land on an alien planet that is full of cows.

@gnasher729 You are an astronaut and land on an alien planet that is full of puppies (moral dilemma) or tarantulas/spiders (disgust). What I mean to show is that through some sort of relationship dogs in the West have managed to live their whole lives without being eaten but loved and culturally assimilated. So there might be hope for us too. We just have to be a good boy :)

My sincere hope is that beings who are vastly more developed than humans have come to the conclusion (and live up to it) that sentient life is a treasure to be guarded. And I sincerely hope that this realization constitutes a great filter: Civilizations which never fully understand that tend to eliminate themselves from the universal gene pool.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica that's a judgment of value, isn't it?

@ac15 The hope is a judgement of value; the reasons for it (self-elimination of aggressive species from the universal gene pool) are not.

This has to be reminding some of Lisa Simpson's tangle with the dusty book titled "How to Cook Humans"... Alien blows dust off... "How to Cook FOR Humans"... Lisa blows dust off... "How to Cook FORTY Humans"... Alien blows dust off... "How to Cook FOR Forty Humans"... then starts crying that Lisa could imagine the aliens might be human-eaters, gets all offended and stuff.  A good scene.

IMO the only attempt is to argue with Kant's Categorical Imperative:

Act only according to that maxim whereby you can at the same time will
that it should become a universal law.

And to point out that there may exist other species more intelligent then the present aliens. Compare also a similar question on this site.

Have my upvote; but I must point out that their universal law appears to be that eating less intelligent species is fine (and they would accept that fate for themselves), so Kant may be of no help here.

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Since Kant's universal laws should be "for all rational beings" and not "for all rational beings that happen to think the same way as we do", this is questionable. You make it sound like the Categorical Imperative would amount to nothing more than the Golden Rule. That is a wrong assumption.

@PhilipKlöcking I'm not at all making that assumption. I'm just saying that there is a possibility that there is nothing that prevents the habit of eating lesser sentient beings from becoming universal law. If that would be the universal law that would prove the point, wouldn't it?

@Peter-ReinstateMonica A Kantian universal law is not the same as a general law (see Formula of natural law). They would basically have to agree that murdering and eating rational beings (ie. moral agents!) that happen to have a lower median IQ as a species necessarily and without fail has to be the norm for all rational beings. How should they justify that?

@PhilipKlöcking Because, for example, all known species in their universe do it? That is at least a strong indicator. Proof of necessary and without fail is, obviously, difficult; but we'd need to prove the opposite which would be, in that universe, clearly harder. Also note that these are superior beings; all arguments we'll make have been beaten to death millions of years ago in their universe. (All under the assumption of the OP that this superior species finds nothing wrong with it, and my additional assumption that they are not outliers.)

Essentially, their response to the Categorical Imperative is "Of course; that's what we do. This is the universal law. Duh."


Would it be possible to convince a hungry alien species that human lives are valuable?

Because your situation is hypothetical, and because they are intelligent and we can communicate with them, yes... of course it would be possible.

How could one of us begin to try to convince them that killing humans for consumption is somehow wrong?

You would probably want to start by understanding what they consider "wrong".  Do they have any morals at all?  Do they show empathy or love towards one another or other species?  Do they keep pets?  Do they forgive?  Is beef a close second on the menu to humans?  How about pork?  (allegedly human flesh is closest to pork...)  Could you strike a deal where we will raise pigs for their meat and be spared?
Only by first deciphering their moral and cultural code, as well as culinary preferences, could you hope to gain enough insight to relate to them in a way that would allow you to plead your case.  And negotiation tactics would be more practical than philosophical.

If there's no way to convince them of such wrongness, could it mean that we were somehow mistaken in holding this belief?

No.  Our own moral code is not invalidated by what another species might believe.

I think this hinges on how "conceptually compatible" they are with us. For example, are we even able to communicate on the same conceptual frameworks? Is their world so more complex/nuanced than ours that sharing ideas is no more effective than my dog trying to share her thoughts with me -- totally different planes of discourse.
If they are in essence just really really brainy versions of humans (e.g., think in 3+1 dimensions, follow cause-and-effect chains linearly, etc) then there is hope we can find a common conceptual ground for discourse.
If not, then we're in trouble.

hi, @Annika: yes, the question assumes we are able to communicate with them, or at least that they are able to 'dumb themselves down a bit' so as to communicate with us, even if we have no hope of understanding their more complex thoughts

@ScottRowe agree

I'm not sure whether that's a philosophical answer but nature shows us ways vulnerable species protect themselves, even if they are physically and mentally inferior:

Look cute to them. Ideally, look like their children. If their children have big ears, slap on big plastic ears.

Look or smell or taste disgusting. If there is something that they find repulsive, try to look or smell or taste like that.

Perform a useful function for them. Take out their trash, play cool jazz, give blowjobs, do whatever might make them reconsider eating you.



It may depend on how, and in what way, they were 'vastly more intelligent' than us. For example, can we assume that they were not always so intelligent, but, like us, they developed to be more intelligent?
Considering that the first 4 bullet points could easily be describing us having travelled to another planet, it may be useful to think of what we would do if in that situation. If there was communication between us and them in an intelligent way (even if our intelligence did not match theirs) I think this would dramatically change the situation.
For example, our most advanced way of communicating is through language, so if they were so much more intelligent than us, I would assume that they could at least match us in this regard and also use language for communication. (Since they are so intelligent, perhaps they could easily decipher our languages and use them to communicate with us) If we could communicate in that way, and they do at least have morals, I think it would make it that much harder for them to eat us. I wonder if cows and pigs developed the ability to talk to us whether we would continue eating them. (I vividly remember crying after having finished reading 'Charlotte's Web'... I am guessing there no vegetarian/vegan aliens by the way.)
Also, despite us being a lot less intelligent than them, if they used to be much less intelligent, but simply developed their intelligence over millennia, then they may be able to view us as similar to them a long time ago. Would we eat stone age people just because they are a lot less intelligent than us? Okay, so you may say 'no' because that would be eating our same species, however, there are many hominins who, although a lot less intelligent than we are now, lived in groups, used tools and behaved in similar ways to humans. Would we choose to eat them if we could, despite them being a different species? Probably not. (Perhaps that boils down to how similar we are to them though, or generally, it may all boil down to how well they can relate themselves to us.) I think the biggest advantage for us would be being able to communicate meaning though language. That might just stop us from all becoming alien stew!

There was a plot point in one of Larry Niven's books where a member of an advanced alien race discovers that the big food animals they had been eating were intelligent. Horror, disgust, shame...

@ScottRowe I can imagine. It seems to be that much harder to consider eating anything the more you can relate it to yourself. Dogs, for example, grow emotional attachments to their owners, and they also show signs of being able to empathize with them. They are incredibly loyal and understand words. There are not many animals that show an understanding of our languages. Use of language for communication is something so important and intrinsically human, I can imagine that we would emotionally share a lot more with animals who can in any way respond to meaning behind our use of language.

hi, @Bevhardy, i think the bit "Would we eat stone age people just because they are a lot less intelligent than us?" is besides the point: here we're not talking about them eating us because we're less intelligent, but rather that they'd have no quals in doing so given that they think humans are delicious

@ac15 Thanks for responding. I was focusing on this: "they find it intuitively obvious that there's nothing wrong in members of one species eating members of other less-intelligent species" I assumed that if they found us to be intelligent enough, on a level acceptable to them, and in a way they can relate themselves to, then despite us being delicious, they would feel the moral obligation to decline eating us. My main point was that it seems so much harder to see other living things as food when there is an ability to relate oneself to them, to see ourselves as similar--or the same--as them.
